# Credit Card (Braintree) is not showing in multishipping billing page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using Braintree Payment method in Magento 2. 
In that Credit Card (Braintree) option is showing in onepage checkout but Credit Card (Braintree) option is not showing in multishipping billing page in magento 2.
[creditcard payment option in onepagecheckout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFD6O.png)

[creditcard payment option is not displaying in multishipping checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDGtW.png)

Comment: I am using magento 2. In that I have enabled Braintree Payment method for credit card payment method.
So now, Credit card payment option is displaying in onepage checkout, but Credit card payment option is not displaying in Multishipping.

Comment: Although I don't have an answer for you about how to patch Magento 2 to add Braintree payment methods into the multishipping checkout forms, it does look like this is a known issue. I'd recommend at least going to the following link and voting/commenting on this so the Magento 2 development staff know to keep it in mind for the next point release: 

[Magento 2 Github Issues Page](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6467)